# Setting defaults in sudoers

Tags: linux, sudo, defaults

I'm trying to set the `Defaults` in an appropriate way for the `pdebuild` usage.
I've got the command alias defined:

```
Cmnd_Alias  PBUILDER = /usr/sbin/pbuilder, /usr/bin/pdebuild, /usr/bin/debuild-pbuilder
```

and I'm trying to set the defaults only for that one:

```
Defaults        env_reset
Defaults!PBUILDER       env_keep="DIST ARCH"
```

This fails with syntax error on the line with `env_reset`. When I comment out the `Defaults!PBUILDER` line, it works just fine. What should I update here to make it work?

---

Additional info:

```
$ sudo -V
Sudo version 1.6.9p17
```

The man page has information about the "Defaults!..." option so this should be ok in theory.

The whole file is:

```
Cmnd_Alias  PBUILDER = /usr/sbin/pbuilder, /usr/bin/pdebuild, /usr/bin/debuild-pbuilder

Defaults    env_reset
Defaults!PBUILDER   env_keep="DIST ARCH"

root    ALL=(ALL) ALL
stan ALL=(ALL) PBUILDER

%engineering    ALL=(ALL) ALL
```

Comment: Can you post the rest of your sudoers file?  What you've posted so far looks fine, and works in my sudoers configuration without a problem.  Also, what version of sudo are you using?

Comment: @larsks - Added the requested info. I'm using debian lenny.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your man page is out-of-sync with respect to the version of sudo that you're using.  I just checked out 1.6.9p23 [aka changeset `5429:f7398cfbac71`] from the [sudo repository](http://www.sudo.ws/repos/sudo), and the `sudoers` man page shows the following syntax:

```
    Default_Type ::= 'Defaults' |
                     'Defaults' '@' Host_List |
                     'Defaults' ':' User_List |
                     'Defaults' '>' Runas_List
```

There's no mention of the `'Defaults' '!' Cmnd_List` syntax available in more recent version.  [This](http://www.irongeek.com/i.php?page=backtrack-3-man/sudoers) appears to be an online version of the 1.6.9 man page which shows the same thing.

Comment: It's there in an example later on, but at the same time, yes, it's missing from the syntax description :/ Some documentation mistake seems to be the most reasonable explanation really.

Answer (score 0):

Just to add to what larsks has said, I've tried your sudoers file in my sudo (1.7.4p5) and it parses fine, no errors.  It's possible that the version you're using doesn't have as sophisticated support for defaults as 1.7, or it may just be a bug.  Is upgrading sudo out of the question?

Comment: Yes, it is out of question. On the other hand, I don't think it's a not-supported option, since this example is in the manpage: `# Override built-in defaults {...} Defaults!PAGERS noexec` for the same version.